# Basic Dealer-Router Socket not working

Tags: ruby, zeromq

I'm trying to implement the basic DEALER - ROUTER socket in ZeroMQ. 
My Question has multiple parts.

Before that, here are my sample scripts

[DEALER SCRIPT](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/ed143ba476b28304f69f)

[ROUTER SCRIPT](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/117a625b521c50825712)

**QUESTION -**

Firstly,The vanilla DEALER SCRIPT of mine is unable to read the message from the SOCKET.

Secondly, When I'm implementing a DEALER or ROUTER PATTERN, is it mandatory to pass the IDENTITY across(as a part of header) i.e can't the message be sent without any IDENTITY.

In other words can a DEALER - ROUTER pattern (can be see below) can co-exists and pass message among themselves without sending identity info in header.

[DEALER WITHOUT ANY IDENTITY](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/859fd728318fe4d75954)

[ROUTER WITHOUT ANY IDENTITY](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/17d41307a9d5451869e6)

because, I'm unable to get it working without the identity as well.

**NOTE** : - The Zeromq ruby library(ruby client) currently in picture is [ffi-rzmq](https://github.com/chuckremes/ffi-rzmq)

Comment: If you don't set the identity explicitly, ZMQ will set an identity.  You don't need to set it on the dealer side, but you need to use it on your router side to send a message back.

Comment: Now that I look closer at your code - the Router *must* receive a message from the Dealer to know what its identity is if you want the Router to be able to send messages to it without setting the identity explicitly.

Comment: @Jason Accepted. So, in case 1 I'm passing the IDENTITY of the DEALER while sending messages from ROUTER can be seen over [here](https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/117a625b521c50825712#file-router-rb-L8). Can you explain the reason why the Message are not getting exchanged in this case though.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows a lot of misunderstandings about how ZMQ works, I suggest you read [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) and follow the Ruby examples to set up your scripts.

Here's the problems that I see:

1. In your DEALER script, you explicitly receive the `identity` - it will never get its own identity as part of the message, this is silently removed by ZMQ because it's not intended to be message data, it's intended to be an "address" used by the ROUTER socket.  So, you're actually receiving the delimiter into your `identity` variable, the message into your `delimiter` variable, and then nothing is left and your `msg` variable is empty.  If you `puts` the values of all three variables, you'll see it.
2. You don't need a ZMQ poller in your DEALER socket.  Pollers are intended to receive messages from multiple sockets, you're only using one socket.  I don't know whether it's actually intended to work with one socket at all, but at any rate it's needless additional complexity, rip it out. [See here for a simple send/receive example from the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/rb:rrclient) (if you just change the socket type to DEALER, add your "particulars" - identity, address, port, etc - and omit the send, it should work for you)
3. In your second example, where you *don't* set an identity, the ROUTER socket doesn't address the message to *any* connected client - you always need to send the client identity as the first frame of the message.  Typically, you'll receive a message from your client, which includes its identity, and you'll use that identity to send the message back.  You're only able to skip that in the first example because your script already knows the identity, "client"